# HTTPS connection gives org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Tags: go, exception, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a HTTPS connection in Golang. Below is my implementation for the same:

```
func main() {
    GcuCertFile = "<path-to-project>/certs/local.localhost.cert"
    GcuKeyFile = "<path-to-project>/certs/local.localhost.key"
    GcuServiceAddr = ":8080"

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) // provide response value beforehand
        w.Write([]byte (message))
    })



    srv := NewServer(mux, ":8080")

    err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS(GcuCertFile, GcuKeyFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Server failed to start: %v", err)
    }
}

func NewServer(mux *http.ServeMux, serverAddress string) *http.Server {
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        // Causes servers to use Go's default ciphersuite preferences,
        // which are tuned to avoid attacks. Does nothing on clients.
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        // Only use curves which have assembly implementations
        CurvePreferences: []tls.CurveID{
            tls.CurveP256,
            tls.X25519, // Go 1.8 only
        },
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
        CipherSuites: []uint16{
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305, // Go 1.8 only
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,   // Go 1.8 only
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        },
    }
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8080",
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        TLSConfig:    tlsConfig,
        Handler:       http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
                        w.Header().Set("Connection", "close")
                        url := "https://" + req.Host + req.URL.String()
                        http.Redirect(w, req, url, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
                        }),
    }
    return srv
}
```

I am requeesting this:

```
GET https://local.localhost:8080
```

And I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
```

Note that I am using certs and keys from another Github repository, would that be the reason I am getting the error for the `GET` request?

Should I create my own `.cert` and `.key`? If yes, how can I create it?

Or is it the problem with the `main.go` code?

Comment: `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException` looks like a Java error. You should to provide more details - how and what is calling that golang TLS server. For me it looks like a client error, not a Golang server problem.

Comment: I know apache is related to Java, but I do not have any Java application running. I cloned the Github project and it works fine in that case, but when I am creating the project myself from scratch, this error comes up.

Comment: You need to provide minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise it is hard to guess what are you doing and where Java exceptions is coming from.

Comment: Which "Github project" do you speak of? Also, your handler will probably always redirect users to the https version, even if they already are on https (there's no check for it?). This might be a cause of the exception (too many redirects?); however you didn't provide any message that could clarify. Another thing that is weird is that the parameter `mux` of `NewServer` is never registered or used.